# How do I use Infinispan Spring Boot Starter together with Infinispan as a 2nd level cache provider for Hibernate?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, infinispan

I am using the [Infinispan Spring Boot Starter](https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/spring_boot/starter.html) (infinispan-spring-boot3-starter-embedded) together with Spring Session distribute the session. This works perfectly.

My application also uses Hibernate (not JPA, but instead using hibernate's SessionFactory). To get a distributed second level cache, I have set the option:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">infinispan</property>
```

This sets the region factory to an implementation of `org.infinispan.hibernate.cache.v60.InfinispanRegionFactory`. This creates a new CacheManager - not reusing the one I already have. The issue with this seems to be that their default transports collide, as my logs fill up with messages like:

> 2023-10-30 13:58:09.311 ERROR 21424 [4,Rainbow-12965] o.j.l.Log4J2LogImpl                      : JGRP000191: failed receiving packet from /172.26.127.126:51131: java.io.EOFException

> 2023-10-30 13:58:09.467 ERROR 21424 [4,Rainbow-12965] o.j.l.Log4J2LogImpl                      : JGRP000191: failed receiving packet from /172.26.127.126:51131: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid magic number 258; needs to be in range [0..100]

Besides, from what I understand Infinispan recommends using only one CacheManager. So what is the method to avoid this, and if possible, reuse the existing CacheManager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a custom region factory:

```
@Component("cacheRegionFactory")
public class CacheManagerReusingInfinispanCacheRegionFactory extends InfinispanRegionFactory {

    @Resource
    private EmbeddedCacheManager cacheManager;

    @Override
    protected EmbeddedCacheManager createCacheManager(Properties properties, ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        return cacheManager;
    }
}
```

and use set the property `cacheRegionFactory` in `org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean`.

One caveat to this approach is that if you use spring-boot-actuator, you may have to exclude `CacheMetricsAutoConfiguration.class` since it appears to pick up some internal Hibernate caches that are not generating statistics, causing a NullPointerException.